# A Generalized Water Filling Problem: $\max_{1^Tx\in[0,1]}\sum_j\ln(\sum_ia_{i,j}x_i)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

The problem is to find $x^*\in\mathbb R^{|I|}$, s.t.:
$$x^*=\operatorname*{arg max}_{1^Tx\in[0,1]}\sum_{j\in J}\ln \left( \sum_{i\in I}a_{i,j}x_i \right)$$

where $(i,j)\in I\times J$ is finite indexes. Positive constant matrix $a\in\mathbb R^{|I\times J|}$.

---

While I am trying to take the KT condition, I get:

$$\partial_{x_k} \sum_j\ln\left(\sum_ia_{i,j}x_i\right)=\lambda \ \ \forall k\in I$$

$$\sum_j\frac{a_{k,j}}{\sum_ia_{i,j}x_i}=\lambda$$

$\lambda$ is a constant.

which does not seem right at all! I don't know how to do the next step.

---

I know what I missed (?). There are actually two constraints ($g$):

$$g_1(x)=1^Tx-1\leq0$$
$$g_2(x)=-1^Tx\leq0.$$

Therefore the KKT condition translates into... The same expression (sad)

---

Not a homework.

Comment: Among the typographical differences between \sum and \Sigma are these: $$ \sum_{i=1}^n \qquad \Sigma_{i=1}^n $$ Notice the positions of the subscripts. I changed $\Sigma$ to $\sum$ in the question.

Comment: @MichaelHardy This is very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain how this is related to a water filling problem ?

Comment: I am not sure what you were hoping to achieve. But the condition on the derivatives seems right to me. The only thing is that you can say a bit more about the $x_i$'s based on the sign of $\lambda$, i.e. if $\lambda>0$, the $\sum x_i = 1$ and if $\lambda<0$, $\sum x_i = -1$.
One more thing that you have to be careful is that there is this implicit condition that $\sum_i a_{ij}x_i>0$. 
Either way, I think at the end of the day it would just give you a non-linear system of equations that would characterize the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as I understood the problem reads as

$$
\max \sum_{j\in J}\ln(a_j^{\top} x)
$$

subjected to

$$
0 \le \left< x,1 \right>\\
\left< x, 1 \right> \le 1
$$

This can be formulated as a Lagrangian multipliers with slack variables problem

$$
L(x,\lambda, \epsilon) = \sum_{j\in J} \ln{a_j^{\top} x}+\lambda_1(\left< x,1 \right>-\epsilon_1^2)+\lambda_2(\left< x,1 \right>-1+\epsilon_2^2)
$$

with stationary points given by the solutions for

$$
\nabla_{x_i}L = \sum_{j\in J}\frac{a_j^i}{a_j^{\top}x}+\lambda_1+\lambda_2 = 0\\
\nabla_{\lambda_1}L = \left< x,1 \right>-\epsilon_1^2=0\\
\nabla_{\lambda_2}L = \left< x,1 \right>-1+\epsilon_2^2=0\\
\nabla_{\epsilon_1}L = \lambda_1\epsilon_1 = 0\\
\nabla_{\epsilon_2}L = \lambda_2\epsilon_2 = 0
$$

I hope this helps.

Comment: Not really making senses (?) Let $a$ be a 2x2 matrix. $a^2=0$, $a^1=1$. Obviously the correct answer is $x_1=1$ and $x_2=0$; however, this is not predicted from our Lagrangian formula

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand what do you intend to tell me